# Requests How to use two different web sites and switching them?

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello is there a way to use two different web site urls and switching them?

I mean i have two different websites like:

```
import requests

session = request.session()

firstPage = session.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
print("Hey! im in first page now!")
secondPage = session.get("https://youtube.com")
print("Hey! im in second page now!")
```

i know a way to do it in selenium like this: `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`

but i want do it in "Requests" so is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium and Requests are two fundamentally different services. Selenium is a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser#:%7E:text=A%20headless%20browser%20is%20a,interface%20or%20using%20network%20communication.) which fully simulates a user. Requests is a python library which simply sends [HTTP requests](https://guides.codepath.com/websecurity/HTTP-Request-Types).

Because of this, Requests is particularly good for scraping static data and data that does not involve javascript rendering (through [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or similar), such as [RESTful APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), which often return [JSON formatted data](https://jsonapi.org/) (with no HTML styling, or page rendering at all). With Requests, after the initial HTTP request is made, the data is saved in an object, and the connection is closed.

Selenium allows you to traverse through complex, javascript-rendered menus and the like, since each page is actually built (under the hood) as if it were being displayed to a user. Selenium encapsulates everything that your browser does except displaying the HTML (including the HTTP requests that Requests is built to perform). After connecting to a page with Selenium, the connection remains open. This allows you to navigate through a complex site where you would need the full URL of the final page to use Requests.

Because of this distinction, it makes sense that Selenium would have a `switch_to_window` method, but Requests would not. The way your code is written, you can access the response to the HTTP get calls which you've made directly though your variables (`firstPage` contains the response from stackoverflow, `secondPage` contains the response from youtube). While using Requests, you are never "in" a page in the sense that you can be with Selenium, since it is an HTTP library and not a full headless browser.

Depending on what you're looking to scrape, it might be better to use either Requests or Selenium.